# jQuery/Javascript beforeunload do something when user chooses to stay on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I have a page that will have user data and questions, if they leave or reload it resets everything. It's working as expected, however, how do you run a function if the user decides to stay on the page? i've looked and can't seem to find an answer. Using jQuery but a vanilla javascript solution is ok too if jQuery doesn't have one.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    return;
});

$(window).bind('unload', function () {
    reset();
});
```

I also don't understand the logic behind removing the ability to give a custom message in the default dialog box. That seems to be where they allowed it before. If theres a solution i missed in the search here please let me know too. Thank you

**EDIT:**
haven't found a way to detect a button press but adding a timeout seems to work. Although doesn't seem to be 100% but will work until someone has a better solution or knows how to detect a button press :)

```
var timeout;
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { console.log('do this'); }, 1000);
    return;
});

$(window).bind('unload', function () {
    reset();
});
```

Comment: Methods got abused so some , if not all, browser vendors opted for default messages only. Also for consistency. I think some may still support custom ones but not certain

Comment: Just beware, some browsers will completely ignore beforeunload scripts, and some  will only pay attention to them if the user has interacted with the page.  (This comes from people - especially the porn industry - abusing the system, and doing nefarious things...).  AFAIK, you can't get a result from the dialog telling you which button was pushed.   But depending on your situation, you could just assume that they stayed and do whatever action you want.   Then if they stay, that action takes effect, and if they leave, they left and won't know that you thought they stayed.

Comment: yes i was going to take it they pressed the stay button but how do i trap the dialog so i know they pressed a button? the beforeunload does something i'm just looking to clear what it does when any button is pressed and the unload function isn't called